# Spacy: retrieve words/keys associated with a particular index

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Given an index corresponding to a row in `<some_model>.vocab.vectors.data`, how can I retrieve the corresponding words / keys?

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

nlp.vocab.vectors.data[6, :]   # gives me the 6th embedding
```

What words/keys map to this 6th embedding? I could do some sort of brute force search by iterating through `*.vocab.vectors.items()` like

```
for key, vector in nlp.vocab.vectors.items():
    # check if vector at my index matches this vector
         # print(nlp.vocab.strings[key])
```

but I'm hoping there's a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a reverse lookup in `nlp.vocab.vectors.key2row` to get all words that use that embedding:

```
for key, row in nlp.vocab.vectors.key2row.items():
    if row == 6:
        print(nlp.vocab.strings[key])
```